# Laravel File Listing & Counting by Filtered File Names

Tags: php, file, laravel, directory-listing

I want to count the number of files I filter by name. I wrote the following code:

```
<?php
    $directory = Config::get('app.app_working_directory')."/".$form_constant["dir"];
    foreach(File::allFiles($directory) as $file)
    {
        if (starts_with($file->getFilename(), $file_tag."-".$id)) {
?>
                        {{HTML::image($form_constant["dir"].'/'.$file->getFilename(), $id, array('class' => 'col-md-3 img-thumbnail img-responsive'))}}
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

But this is just for listing files on directory. My stored files like this:

```
machine-parts-103-09122015150511.jpg
machine-parts-103-09122015150515.jpg
machine-parts-1072-09122015143157.jpg
```

Format: machine-part-$id-microtime(). How I can count like a just filename starting "machine-part-$id-*"? Example for this file names: "Total File:2" for "machine-parts-103-*". Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the glob function to count the number of files that matches a wildcard like this:

```
glob("/path/to/directory/machine-parts-103-*.jpg");
```

This will return you an array with all the files names that matches that pattern and you can count the number of items in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem. Thank you oscar.rpr. My code:

```
<?php
    $directory = Config::get('app.app_working_directory').'/'.$table_constant["dir"];
    $file_count = count(glob($directory.'/'.$file_tag.'-'.$default_table_data->$table_constant["column"].'-*'));
?>
<td>{{$file_count}}</td>
```